# How to refer to Entity Framework DbContext from MVC business objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, dbcontext

I'm starting a new ASP.NET MVC project. In my last project, one of the biggest code smells was how I passed around the Entity Framework DbContext, stored it in HttpContext.Current, called SaveChanges() in my rendering event, and did all manner of (probably unseemly) related things.

Suppose that my unit of work always corresponds to a web request. What is the right way to create a DbContext, share that context to a business library (e.g. an assembly outside the MVC project responsible for processing some workflow activities), share result models back to my controller, and persist any changes?

I'll be honest, I don't know much about dependency injection. It sounds like it should be related, but I don't see how it would get me a shared context instance between my controller and my business processes in an external assembly.

If I only needed it from controllers, it would be easy. I'd stick to HttpContext. But now HttpContext has spilled over to my external library. Do I just define an interface that returns the current DbContext, and base an implementation of that on HttpContext?

Hope that's clear what I'm asking, as I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency injection definitely sounds like what you are after here. My preference is ninject so below is a bit of an example of how I do this with EF.

Install Ninject.MVC3 (available on nuget)

Go to \app_start\NinjectWebCommon.cs (added by the above package) and add the following to the RegisterServices method

```
kernel.Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope(); //binding in the context in request scope, this will let us use it in our controllers
```

Inside a controller consume the context as follows

```
public class MyController : ....{
   private readonly MyContext _context;
   public MyController(MyContext context){ _context = context; }
   //Do stuff with _context in your actions
}
```

This is a really simple example for you to try there are plenty of better ways to structure this as your application grows (such as ninject modules) but this will demonstrate how DI works.

A few things to note, Always make sure you bind the context in requestscope (or more frequently) as DBContext has a nasty habit of growing quite bit if it sticks around too long.

In terms of sharing it with your external stuff that can be injected too, eg

```
public class MyExternalLogic{
    public MyExternalLogic(MyContext context){....}
}

public class MyController : ....{
   private readonly MyContext _context;
   public MyController(MyContext context, MyExternalLogic logic){ _context = context; ...}
   //Do stuff with _context in your actions
}
```

In the above the same instance of DbContext will be used for both MyController and MyExternalLogic. Ninject will handle the creation of both objects.

There are also a bunch of other DI containers available which will give you very similar experiences. I highly recommend DI as it helps a lot with unit test-ability as well.

For some more examples of how I use Ninject to structure my MVC apps check out some of my projects on github, such as https://github.com/lukemcgregor/StaticVoid.Blog

Comment: Thank you. Looks great. I'll tell you that I think the biggest problem I'm actually having with it is that for some reason I don't trust it. :) Maybe it's just been a long week.

Comment: @shannon i suppose trust is earned, DI has definitally earned mine, sure sometimes it has some issues but having said that its pretty rare i write something without DI now

Comment: Do you also refer to a user identity object via DI?

Comment: @shannon I personally dont but i dont see why not if you wrapped it up. I wouldnt pass the user straight from HttpContext around

Comment: Thank you Luke. Yeah, I have a "visitor" object in this project, which holds a session ID for tracking/restricting concurrency, caches any user-specific data retrieved on that request from persistence, and has some more complex rights calculation wrapped up in it.

Comment: Although, I currently pass it a scope-singleton-storage interface (again, basically just HttpContext). Ninject includes that in the web kit, so I could pull that out of the visitor object.